# Is coconut oil the best for high-temperature cooking?

Tags: nutrition

In a conversation with a colleague, it was suggested that common cooking oils such as olive oil will "go rancid" when heated, causing them to break down, for them to lose their nutritional value, and for them to become in some way bad for you. Further, it was suggested that coconut oil is the only oil that does not suffer from this behaviour.

[Authority Nutrition](http://authoritynutrition.com/healthy-cooking-oils/) somewhat supports this claim:

> When it comes to high heat cooking, coconut oil is your best choice.

Meanwhile, [Healthwyze](http://healthwyze.org/index.php/component/content/article/539-why-rancid-healthy-oils-are-more-dangerous-than-the-bad-oils.html) contradicts it:

> Coconut oil should only be used in low heat or no heat recipes.

Is coconut oil suitable for high temperature cooking? Is it the 'best' at avoiding going rancid when cooked?

Comment: Has anyone heard this claim? Is it notable?

Comment: best... for what? No oil goes rancid during cooking. Oils go rancid over a long period of time (long varying from days to weeks or months, depending on the type of oil and how it's been treated).

Comment: This seems like a question for the cooking stackexchange.

Comment: @Flimzy: Source? Rancidification is an oxidation reaction, and many such reactions occur much more rapidly at high temperature, so it's not totally implausible.

Comment: I posted this question here rather than on cooking as my initial research indicated the presence of a significant industry of coconut-oil promoters overlapping with the health fringe. Therefore I felt I needed some baloney busting help from this SE to cut through it all, rather than a strictly cooking-oriented response.

Comment: I think is this question is supposed to survive it would be helpful to remove "best" and focus on rancid.

Comment: FWIW, Coconut oil's smoke point is [about midrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_point) compared to other cooking oils.

Comment: It is good that the question was posted here, because we'd close it the moment it appears on cooking. Both coconut oil and olive oil will pyrolise starting at a certain temperature called the "smoking point". In general, olive oil, especially EVOO, has a rather low one. This has been discussed to death on Cooking. But the claim that it is unhealthy to eat oil beyond the smoking point is a nutritional one, which we consider off topic, it is the first of our three site-specific closing reasons.

Comment: I'll also warn anybody who uses smoking point charts to answer here: they are all very imprecise. They tend to list oils by source (e.g. one number for maize oil, another one for safflower oil) but in reality, the smoking point depends on the exact chemical composition of the oil, which differs depending on processing method and cultivar. So, "safflower oil" has a wide range of smoking points, not the point value commonly shown on charts.

Answer (score 4):

Coconut Oil does suffer from this behaviour, and its smoke point is 175 +/- 4°C which is lower than other common cooking oils:

- Source: [Emissions of volatile aldehydes from heated cooking oils](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/248511136_Emissions_of_volatile_aldehydes_from_heated_cooking_oils/file/72e7e5290f8e56f0e5.pdf)

> When the temperature of the oil was above its smoke point, the emission of volatiles drastically increased, implying that oils with low smoke point, such as coconut, are not useful for deep-frying operations
>   
>   So, your friend and Health Nutrition are wrong. Healthwyze is right.